# Change all api calls URL react when in production

Tags: reactjs, api, url

I would like to know if it is possible to alter all the api calls made from my react app to my backend server. I used to have the static files to sit around in my project root directory, so when I made an api call with `axios` like `await axios.get('/api/my-endpoint')` it all worked fine and my requests were translated to `GET https://www.example-url.com/api/my-endpoint`. But now I am migrating to AWS EC2 and decided to serve static files from AWS S3. So now since the api is in a remote server all my api calls are broken. I need to replace all api calls to `https://www.another-example-url.com/api/...`. I know I can set the new URL in an environment variable, but that would force me to manually alter all of the api URLs in my front-end codebase. I would not be very happy to do this, since there are almost a thousand of them.

I tried to set the axios baseURL like so:

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({

  baseURL: "www.another-example-url.com"
});

export default instance;
```

but then all the requests were translated to `GET https://www.example-url.com/www.another-example-url.com/api/my-endpoint`

Is there a lazy way of doing this? Or do I have to manually alter them all?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set this using "proxy" field in package.json file of client side. Just add following line

```
...
 "proxy": "https://www.another-example-url.com",
...
```

edit: I almost forgot that you were asking for production build. So [react-amazing-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-amazing-proxy) is an alternate to create-react-app proxy which can have feature to use proxy in production build.

Another lazy way, if you are familiar with docker, would be to Dockerize your development built.

Comment: Nope, I don't think you can. `proxy` only works for development mode as the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) says. While in production mode, the URL is set as the root

Comment: @OmarOmeiri have you tried react-amazing-proxy